# Google maps API for Blackberry

Tags: javascript, google-maps, blackberry

Is it possible to have a site where you can press a button and open the Google Maps Mobile API of BB to get the developed map with the information i charged? I'm working on a site that needs to show different routes, restaurants, Gas Stations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry has its own maps API.

See [this link](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17966/Maps_API_overview_1248836_11.jsp).

Comment: Hello Zack Thank you for the answer. See my comment to JaakL answer to see if you can give me some light here...

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry maps API is pretty limited, basically only thing you can do is show a point on map. Advantage is that it is totally free, and it is pre-bundled with many (but not all) BB devices. But if it is not there, then you are stuck.

There are third party APIs, for example my company has done http://www.nutiteq.com/rim-blackberry-mapping-api-sdk , feel free to have feedback about it, even directly to me.

Comment: I don't know if you have clear what i'm trying to do. It's a customized map with information about services (gas stations, restaurants, hotels, etc) in different rutes in Argentina.

Comment: What i need it's a Mobile app to get the geolocation of the user and shows in this mobile device (through Google Mpas for example) his location and the different Landmarks added to this map. It is possible to show through a website by entering from a mobile web browser? Or i have to create a new App for different systems like iphone, android, RIM, etc? In this case, do you develop this customized maps? Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing , but no luck with BB maps.

http://www.nutiteq.com/rim-blackberry-mapping-api-sdk

are not still optimized for BB 6.0 FYI!